# inverse limit as a functor

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I have a question about inverse limits based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit .

In the section "general definition" there is noted that an inverse system is a contravariant functor $I\to C$ (I adopt all teh notations from wikipedia).

1. Question: how does the contravriant functor $I\to C$ look like?
   Is it: $i\mapsto X_i$ (objects) and $(i\mapsto j)\;\mapsto \; (A_j\mapsto A_i)$ for $i\le j$?
2. Question: How to understand $\varprojlim:C^{I^{op}}\to C$ as a functor, what is $C^{I^{op}}$, is it a functor-category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the very definition of a functor, a contravariant functor $I\to C$ is indeed as you put it (note that $I$ is not necessarily the category associated to an ordered set, although it is often the case).

Then $C^{I^{op}}$, which is indeed by definition the category of functors from $I^{op}$ to $C$, is the category of inverse systems in $C$ associated to $I$ (which corresponds roughly to the "shape" of the diagrams).

So the functor $\varprojlim:C^{I^{op}}\to C$ associates to every inverse system an object in $C$ : its limit.

Comment: But the inverse limit also remembers morphisms to the vertices, thus the codomain shouldn't be $C$.

Comment: @Student It is extremely common to speak about "the limit" when you mean "the underlying object of the limit". Just like most people would I think agree it is just fine to say that the product of two sets is a set (as opposed to a set with canonical projections). It depends on the level of precision you need.